# Didn't understand relationship 'opportunity__c' in field path

Tags: soql, salesforce1-app

> Select id, Account.Type from opportunity__c

I create a custom object opportunity and make relational on Account__c and account data type lookup but above query does not run and give below error

> "Select id, Account.Type from opportunity__c ^ ERROR at
>   Row:1:Column:12 Didn't understand relationship 'Account' in field
>   path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to
>   append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference
>   your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you made this custom object then the field for account is also custom so the query should be like this:

```
Select id, Account__r.Type from opportunity__c
```